# Borrar datos selecionados del datagridview

Tags: c#, datagrid

Hola lo que quiero hacer es borrar los datos seleccionados en el datagriedview
lo que llevo de mi codigo  boton "Quitar"(me da erores) en la linea
`foreach(DataGridViewRow c in DataGridViewSelectionArea.Rows)`
 :

```
    private void BtnQuitar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      foreach(DataGridViewRow item in DataGridViewSelectionArea.SelectedRows)
      {
          DataGridViewSelectionArea.RemoveAt(item.Index);

      }

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque no es la columna 1 es la columna 0 `c.Cells[0].Value`, otra cosa no puedes afectar la colección a la que le haces un `foreach` hablo de agregar o eliminar sus elementos.

Comment: Sigue igual colega

Comment: Se más especifico cual es tu error que dice tu error.

Comment: `Does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type Parrot.Common.CustomComponent.CustomDataGridView' Could be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Ya cambie el codigo y ya compila pero al momento de darle al boton "quitar" me mande este error
`NulReferenceException was unhandled
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: El codigo ya esta editado arriba

Comment: No puedes afectar la colección a la que le haces un `foreach` en un ciclo no lo puedes hacer, debes guardar todas las filas en una lista y luego de eso borrar todos los elementos del `DataGridView` que aparezcan en esa lista. En que linea te da el error `NulReferenceException`, se genera porque no esta llegando nada, coloca un `breakpoint` y revisa.

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que pudes usar el metodo remove directo

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgRoot.SelectedRows)
        {
            dgRoot.Rows.Remove(item);
        }

        dgRoot.Refresh();
```

Comment: De donde sale en DgRoot, lo debo cambiar por el nombre de mi datagridview?

Comment: dgRoot es el nombre del DataGrid es irrelevante el nombre que tenga